# Execute command in a variable don't execute the latter part of a pipe

Tags: bash, variables, pipe

I have found that the command expanded from variable won't run the latter parts in a pipe. For example, as following `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

y='echo hello man | awk "{print \$1}"'
$y
eval $y

y='echo hello'
$y
```

The output of the script is:

```
hello man | awk "{print \$1}"
hello
hello
```

The first `$y` only execute `echo hello man` but not execute `awk "{print $1}"` of the pipe. That's why?
My bash version is `4.3.48`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the variable is expanded after the pipes and redirection is already done.  So in that case `|` is just another argument to `echo`, not a pipe that's interpreted by the shell.

Recommended reading: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

When executing the command

```
echo hello man | awk '{print $1}'
```

the shell will see the `|` and setup a pipeline, on one side it will run the command `echo hello man` and on the other `awk '{print $1}'`.  The commands then get subjected to word splitting so you run the command `echo` with 2 arguments: `hello` and `man`.  On the other side you run the command `awk` with a single argument (because of the quoting) `"{print \$1}"`

When that command is stored as a string though the shell first looks at the command `$y` and sees no redirection to do.  It then expands `$y` and then does word splitting on it.  It gets expanded to the same looking string, but now it's too late for redirection.  So it gets split into the words `echo`, `hello`, `man`, `|`, `awk`, `"{print`, `\$1}"` (note that the argument to `awk` now gets split because the quotes inside the string are part of the string, not syntactical)

The first word in that list is `echo` so that's the command, and all the rest of the words are passed as arguments to it, which is why you see the output

```
hello man | awk "{print \$1}"
```

When you do the `eval` line, it takes that same string and tells `bash` to parse it as though it had been typed so the pipe once again becomes syntatical and causes the pipeline.

Because `echo` puts its arguments on the same line it's a little tougher sometimes to see what's happening, if we replace it with `printf '%s\n'` each argument will become its own line though:

```
$ y='printf %s\n hello man | awk "{print \$1}"'
$ $y
hello
man
|
awk
"{print
\$1}"
```

Comment: Variable is expanded after the pipes and redirection. But When is `echo` executed? Is `echo` not a part of the pipe?

Comment: @zhenguoli no, the variable gets expanded to  the string you assigned to it, then that gets subject to word splitting.  The first word is treated as the command and all the rest are arguments to that command.  So `echo` is the first word and is the command, no redirection is processed, so everything else, including the pipe, is an argument to `echo`

Comment: You mean the Bash treats it as a `echo` command, not a pipe. In other words, the pipe is not done.

Comment: Sort of, if it were a pipe you'd have both an `echo` command and an `awk` command, with the stdout of one as the stdin of the other.  In this case though, the pipe is not seen by the shell as having that special meaning--it doesn't appear until it's too late for the shell to do that.  The `|` is just another part of the string that's passed to the `echo` command, and because of the the string "awk" is also an argument passed to `echo` and so forth.  There's no pipeline and there is only one command executed instead of 2

Comment: Thanks very much, I probably get it.

Comment: @zhenguoli I tried to expand a bit on it, to hopefully help make it a little more clear

Comment: Thank you sincerely. There may be much relevant about how bash parses the command line. I should read more about it.